# How to get property from JSON model filled with oData?

Tags: json, data-binding, odata, sapui5

Im trying to get property from oData return model. I set data in success callback function from oData to JSON model.

```
  oODataModel.read("/ConnObjSet?$filter=Objecttype eq 'CONNOBJ' and ConnObject eq '20000000002'",
                        true,
                        true,
                        false,
                        function _OnSuccess(oData, oResponse){
                        var oJSON = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
                        oJSON.setData(oData);                           
                        sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oJSON, "ConnectionObject");
                        },
```

This is my JSON object in console log and highlighted property I want to get. I want to get every 15 Buspartner number from whole array.

[image]

And this is what I tried to get property:

```
 var oLog = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("ConnectionObject").oData.results;

 console.log(oLog);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array of objects, you can get an array of properties from each of these objects by using the [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function.

So in your case:

```
var aResults = this.getView().getModel().getProperty("/results");
var aBuspartner = aResults.map(function (r) { return r.Buspartner});
var oJSONModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oJSONModel.setProperty("/resultarray", aBuspartner)
```

Comment: Then I get property with .getProperty("/resultarray"); . Thanks it works great too.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
var aResults = this.getView().getModel().getProperty("/results");
var oJSONModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oJSONModel.setProperty("/resultarray",new Array())
for(var i = 0; i<aResults.lenght;i++){ 
    oJSONModel.getProperty("/resultarray").push(aResults[i].Buspartner) 
}
```

Comment: This works nice thanks .getProperty("/results/0/Buspartner"); But I want to get properties from all objects not only single one. like this example it return 1 value from object 0.

Comment: this.getView().getModel().getProperty("/results") will return the array, then you need to iterate over this array. Normally you would bind this array to a control like a list.

Comment: My goal is to construct new JSON model with all 15 values from all objects with property /Buspartner. I don't know if this is good approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to add a filter and select to your oData.read

The oData-URL
    http://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products
selects all Product with all their properties

```
http://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products?$filter=UnitsInStock%20eq%2017
```

shows only Products with "UnitsInStock=17"

```
http://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products?$select=ProductID&$filter=UnitsInStock%20eq%2017
```

selects only the ProductID of Products with "UnitsInStock=17"

so

```
oODataModel.read("/ConnObjSet?$select=Buspartner&$filter=Objecttype eq 'CONNOBJ' and ConnObject eq '20000000002'"
...
```

should get the filtered Buspartners directly.